# MVC 5, execute javascript after POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some simple JavaScript in an Edit view, which is executed on jquery document.ready function.

The javascript, finds "checked" checkboxes and adds a "disabled" attribute to them all good and well.

however, after I do a post(Edit) to the server, the checkbox's are no longer disabled. I am using Html.BeginForm()

How can I run the same script after this post?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var chkboxes = $('[type="checkbox"]');

        $.each(chkboxes, function (i, value) {
            if (value.checked) {
                $(value).attr("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

EDIT:

I am posting via Html.BeginForm() on submit button click.

Once, the user clicks on a checkbox, a current date time value is added to the model value. So, I disable the "checked" checkbox permanently.

The adding of "disabled" attribute has to be dynamic for this reason, hence not using html.

Comment: How do you post to the server?

Comment: What is your controller code? And what is the purpose of disabling the checkboxes (and why use javascript instead of html?)

Comment: @AnamulHasan check update :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke check update :)

Comment: But your code script is executed when the page is first loaded so your last edit makes no sense. And you still have not shown your controller code oe explained why you eant to prevent your checkboxes posting a value

Comment: You have misunderstood, I am not trying to prevent checkboxes sending the value. I am simply trying to keep the "disabled" state in the UI

Comment: I will update the op again. please wait

Comment: Add **input** in this line `var chkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');`

Comment: Disabled inputs do not post a value so you are preventing the values being submitted!

Comment: @BasantaMatia that is what I need, however, now only one checkbox is "checked and disabled"

Comment: I see, okay, but for my case that is fine. I do not want to overwrite any values once the check box is selected. Each checkbox is associated with a different model value.@StephenMuecke

Comment: I think, I have confused you a bit, with lack of information. I have a view model, which I send back to the server. The value that are bind to the form are hidden, hence they do go back to the server. And by disabling the checkbox, I validate in the controller, if checkbox is true, do not update any values.@StephenMuecke

Comment: All your properties bound to checkboxes will be `false`!!! And unless you show your code, no one can help you.

Comment: @Haris, you don't need javascript to do that. In mvc this can be done in the view based on information in the model, tempdata, etc.

Comment: @derloopkat can you point me to an example or source?

Comment: jheez you are correct i misunderstood what you were talking about @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable all your checkbox in page load, then do like this,

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('disabled', true);
```

If some of your checkbox are already checked in page load and you want to disabled only them(because you don't want to edit them), then,

```
 $('#myForm input:checkbox').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
  })
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks, but the form does not have a name. I am using Html.BeginForm() and yes I want to be able to the latter

Comment: No issue. You can remove the myForm, like `$('input:checkbox')`

Comment: but this will disable them all?

Comment: No man. There is a if condition. If it's checked then only it will disable. Or else you can add a ID to your BeginForm and use that just like i have mentioned.

Comment: That means all your checkbox are true, that is fetching from your DB. Then all should disabled, that is what you want, mentioned in your question.

Comment: I did check that, they are not. anyway, this points me in the right direction. I will figure it out thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149316/discussion-between-basanta-matia-and-haris).